# Youtube video shows on click of image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've looked at a few implementations of this and so far none have worked so I'm resorting to posting. The concept is: a placeholder image which once clicked changes into the video and autoplays.

Current HTML:

```
<div id="ytvideo" style="display:none;">
    <iframe width="939" height="528" id="ytvideo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<img class="aligncenter size-full" id="homevideo" alt="placeholder" src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/placeholder.jpg" width="940" height="548" />
```

Current JS:

```
jQuery(document).on('click','#homevideo',function(e){
    jQuery('#ytvideo').show();
    jQuery('#homevideo').hide();
    jQuery('#ytvideo').attr("src","www.youtube.com/embed/[myvidid]?autoplay=1");
    jQuery("#ytvideo").attr('src', jQuery("#ytvideo", parent).attr('src') + '?autoplay=1');
});
```

I've looked at trying to reload the `iframe` but that doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

**MARKED: FIXED**

Comment: I think will be better by using youtube API's see: https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started#data_api

Comment: I think you've missed a "http://" there, making the iframe effectively point to  `http://www.yourdomain.com/directory/www.youtube.com/embed/[myvidid]?autoplay=1`

Comment: @Roman seems to have pretty much got it here. That was the first problem. The second problem I realized myself... the iframe is the same name as the div and so it was attaching the src to the div, not the iframe. :(

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the protocol - `www.youtube.com/…` would link to folder on the server.

With protocol it works fine – I’d suggest creating the whole iframe dynamically though, because with an empty src attribute at the beginning it would load the same page it is embedded in.

```
<div id="ytvideo" style="display:none;"></div>
<!-- replaced your image with a span here for fiddle -->
<span id="homevideo" data-vidid="mbOEknbi4gQ">click me</span>

$(document).on('click','#homevideo',function(e){
    $('#homevideo').hide();
    $('#ytvideo').html('<iframe width="939" height="528" id="ytvideo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+$(this).attr("data-vidid")+'?autoplay=1"></iframe>').show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HuVqm/

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in one of the comments, you can get both the img and the video from the api.

This would be good if you didn't want to maintain the image, just wanted it to pull through from YouTube. (However I am not sure that YT provide an image as large as 939 so in your case you might still want to use your own image). I have put in a random channel name 'RIDEChannel' feel free to change that with your channel name.

```
<div id="vid"></div>

$.getJSON("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/RIDEChannel/uploads?max-results=1&v=2.1&alt=jsonc&callback=?", function (myvid) {
    var vid = $("#vid");
    $.each(myvid.data.items, function (i, item) {
        vid.append("<img width='300' height='250' src='" + item.thumbnail.hqDefault + "'>");
        $(document).on("click", "#vid img", function (event) {
            vid.append("<iframe width='300' height='250' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + item.id + "?autoplay=1' frameborder='0'></iframe>");
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The API provides an image `snippets.thumbnails.maxres` worth checking

Answer (score 0):

So the problem laid with the youtube url missing the http:// prefix and also for the fact that the iframe name was the same as the div it was enclosed in. (How silly of me) Thus it was attaching the SRC to the div, not the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

### Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/pH7h9/2/)

Try this,

First you cannot have same id for more than one elements `<div id="ytvideo"` and `<iframe id="ytvideo"`

`[myvidid]`  in  `http://www.youtube.com/embed/[myvidid]?autoplay=1`   should be replaced with the id of the video

### html

```
<div id="ytvideo1" style="display:none;">
    <iframe width="939" height="528" id="ytvideo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<img class="aligncenter size-full" id="homevideo" alt="placeholder" src="http://thefabweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/6191814472_fa47c79b67_b-900x600.jpg" width="940" height="548" data-vid='DBNYwxDZ_pA'/>
```

### code

```
jQuery(document).on('click','#homevideo',function(e){
jQuery('#ytvideo1').show();
jQuery('#homevideo').hide();
jQuery('#ytvideo').attr("src","http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+$(this).data('vid')+"?autoplay=1");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 1 video, it could be useful to store the url to the video in the html and use a class instead of an id.

Also, if you put the preview image into the background, behind the video, it will stay there until the iframe has loaded, reducing that "flickering" effect when clicked.

I also restructured the markup a bit to reduce redundancy, here I specify the size of the video and the video id only once.

Also, you should use jQuery's `.one('click')` instead of `.click()`, since you want that event listener removed after it has fired the first time.

html:

```
<div class="ytvideo" 
     data-video="73sgatbknvo"
     style="width:939px; height:528px; background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/939/528/)">

     <div class="seo">
         Have a meaningful description of the video here
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ytvideo {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.ytvideo iframe {
    border-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.ytvideo .seo {
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.ytvideo[data-video]').one('click', function() {
    $(this).html('<iframe allowfullscreen  src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'+$(this).data("video")+'?autoplay=1"></iframe>');
});
```

If you want to support browsers with no script support, you'd have to add a "noscript" element in the .ytvideo div that already contains the iframe.

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6ARc7/